# Pandas: Compare rows from two columns with several RegEx and copy right ones into a own column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'd like to ask for help for my problem. So, I have this dataframe with two columns and have a huge dataset of about 9500~ rows with 2 columns. Sometimes I have to take a subset from column A, sometimes from B - depending on the RegEx. But I have more than two of them (RegEx) but they are kinda unique. The result should be written into a third column with the 'right' value. It must be done with RegEx.

I hope I can make it more clear with this (small) example:

**Input**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['No animal', 'No animal', 'Zoo One', 'Zoo Two', 'Me-Lo-N', 'Ap-Pl-E'], 'B': ['EE.Elephant', 'SS.Penguin', 'EE.Elephant', 'SS.Penguin', 'GB One', 'GB Two']})

>>> df
           A            B
0  No animal  EE.Elephant
1  No animal   SS.Penguin
2    Zoo One  EE.Elephant
3    Zoo Two   SS.Penguin
4    Me-Lo-N       GB One
5    Ap-Pl-E       GB Two
```

Now I 'identified' several patterns.

- If in column 'A' is 'No animal', take the value from column 'B' no matter what.
- If in column 'A' is 'Zoo ...' and in column 'B' something like 'XX.Animalname', take the left value from 'A' (Zoo ...)
- If in column 'A' is something like 'XX-YY-Z' and in column 'B' 'GB ...', take the value/s from column 'A'.

**The output should look like**:

```
           A            B            C
0  No animal  EE.Elephant  EE.Elephant
1  No animal   SS.Penguin   SS.Penguin
2    Zoo One  EE.Elephant      Zoo One
3    Zoo Two   SS.Penguin      Zoo Two
4    Me-Lo-N       GB One      Me-Lo-N
5    Ap-Pl-E       GB Two      Ap-Pl-E
```

I built follow RegEx for them:

- (No animal)
- (\w{2}..*) f.e. for EE. Bla
- (Zoo.*) f.e. for Zoo...
- (\w{2}-.+-.+) f.e. for Me-Lo-N
- (GB.+) ...

That's it. What's the best approach to compare specific RegEx to eachother between two columns and paste the answer into a own column?

Really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and [str.match](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) as below to get your desired output.

```
df['C']=np.select([df.A=='No animal', df.A.str.match('Zoo.*') & df.B.str.match('\w{2}[.].'), df.A.str.match('\w{2}-.+-.+') & df.B.str.match('GB.+')], [df.B, df.A,df.A])
```

print(df)

**Output**

```
            A             B     C
0   No animal   EE.Elephant     EE.Elephant
1   No animal   SS.Penguin      SS.Penguin
2   Zoo One     EE.Elephant     Zoo One
3   Zoo Two     SS.Penguin      Zoo Two
4   Me-Lo-N     GB One          Me-Lo-N
5   Ap-Pl-E     GB Two          Ap-Pl-E
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer really helped me a lot!